# Erro docker-compose após remover containers

Tags: docker

Fui apagar uns containers no docker para subi-los novamente e o docker-compose não ta subindo mais as imagens.

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
Building application Traceback (most recent call last):   

 File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 96, in create_archive PermissionError: 
  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/richar/Área de Trabalho/projeto mensi2/projeto-mensis/mysql/data/ca-key.pem'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
File "compose/cli/main.py", line 127, in perform_command
File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1085, in up
File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1081, in up
File "compose/project.py", line 527, in up
File "compose/service.py", line 360, in ensure_image_exists
File "compose/service.py", line 1084, in build
File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 159, in build
File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 31, in tar
File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 100, in create_archive
OSError: Can not read file in context: /home/richar/Área de Trabalho/projeto mensi2/projeto-mensis/mysql/data/ca-key.pem
[5820] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Eu sou novo no linux, como eu posso corrigir isso?

Comment: como você removeu as imagens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta dando erro de permissão em um arquivo do MySQL, provavelmente porque você está criando um volume do banco setando uma pasta local,

Você pode apagar a pasta MySQL, isso apagará o banco

```
sudo rm -R ./mysql/data
```

ou mudar a permissão

```
sudo chmod 777 -R ./mysql
```

Tente fazer isso no diretório do projeto

Comment: Valeu Gabriel Sousa era isso mesmo obrigada pelo salve.